# how to identify selected notification from multiple Notification android?

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notification-bar

Here is my MyFirebaseMessagingService i am using it to generate notification in application.

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {   
 private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    //Displaying data in log

    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    Log.d(TAG, "Notification MESSAGE Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    Log.d(TAG, "onMessageReceived: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getTag());



//Calling method to generate notification  

 sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(),remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());

}

//This method is only generating push notification
//It is same as we did in earlier posts
private void sendNotification(String messageBody, String title) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationDetailActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(Appconstant.NOTIFICATION, messageBody);
    intent.putExtra(Appconstant.TITLE, title);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify((int) ((new Date().getTime() / 1000L) % Integer.MAX_VALUE), notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

}

Here I am Able to generate nultiple notification but not able to identify  perticular notification from multiple notification in notification bar, now it is displaying Latest Notification's Title and Message body, Guys please help me.

Comment: you can identify each notification using notification id. right now you are passing value (int) ((new Date().getTime() / 1000L) % Integer.MAX_VALUE) as notification id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
notificationManager.notify((int) ((new Date().getTime() / 1000L) % Integer.MAX_VALUE), notificationBuilder.build());
```

Replace `(int) ((new Date().getTime() / 1000L) % Integer.MAX_VALUE)` with an identification logic of your own (e.g incremental integers).

Comment: Thanks for the comment but this is not the issue, Problem is when I have multiple messages It is taken the title and Body of last Notification.

Comment: .setContentTitle(someId+"-"+title)
            .setContentText(someId+"-"+messageBody)

Comment: problem is that how to get every notificationId, How can I categorized every Notification.

Comment: Your questions are very broad and not clear. Where do you want to get the notificationId? Categorize into what? Like what exactly? any examples?

Comment: @Mohammad I got the answer That is we need to use something changing in 2nd perameter  of pending Intent-------

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Comment: Great. Glad you found your answer !